# gvim automatic show foldcolumn when there are folds in a file

Tags: vim, folding, fold

I know you can use

```
set foldcolumn=1
```

to enable fold column

but is there a way to automatic turn it on only when there are folds exist in the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably you can create a function to check if the file has any folds, like:

```
function HasFoldedLine() 
    let lnum=1 
    while lnum <= line("$") 
        if (foldclosed(lnum) > -1) 
            return 1 
        endif 
        let lnum+=1 
    endwhile 
    return 0 
 endfu
```

Now you can use it with some `autocommand`, e.g.:

```
au CursorHold * if HasFoldedLine() == 1 | set fdc=1 | else |set fdc=0 | endif
```

HTH

Comment: I intend to, later :)

Comment: Couple years late to the party, but I think I came up with a faster method.

Answer (score 8):

My method is faster than @Zsolt Botykai's when files get large enough. For small files I'd imagine the time difference is insignificant. Instead of checking every line for a fold, the function simply tries to move between folds. If the cursor never moves, there are no folds.

```
function HasFolds()
    "Attempt to move between folds, checking line numbers to see if it worked.
    "If it did, there are folds.

    function! HasFoldsInner()
        let origline=line('.')  
        :norm zk
        if origline==line('.')
            :norm zj
            if origline==line('.')
                return 0
            else
                return 1
            endif
        else
            return 1
        endif
        return 0
    endfunction

    let l:winview=winsaveview() "save window and cursor position
    let foldsexist=HasFoldsInner()
    if foldsexist
        set foldcolumn=1
    else
        "Move to the end of the current fold and check again in case the
        "cursor was on the sole fold in the file when we checked
        if line('.')!=1
            :norm [z
            :norm k
        else
            :norm ]z
            :norm j
        endif
        let foldsexist=HasFoldsInner()
        if foldsexist
            set foldcolumn=1
        else
            set foldcolumn=0
        endif
    end
    call winrestview(l:winview) "restore window/cursor position
endfunction

au CursorHold,BufWinEnter ?* call HasFolds()
```

Answer (score 3):

(Shameless self *plugin*)

I created a plugin to do this called [Auto Origami](https://github.com/benknoble/vim-auto-origami), modeled on @SnoringFrog's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29086570/4400820).

Drop the following example into your vimrc after installing it to see the magic happen (and read `:help auto-origami` to find out how to fine-tune it):

```
augroup autofoldcolumn
  au!

  " Or whatever autocmd-events you want
  au CursorHold,BufWinEnter * AutoOrigamiFoldColumn
augroup END
```